# Windows Vista to Windows 7 Backup

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, backup

If I perform a system backup with the Backup and Restore Center in Windows Vista, can I open/restore it in Windows 7?

Comment: Edit your post to include: What software you used for the backup, what exactly you backed up, why you are wanting to do this in the first place. I you are trying to migrate from Vista to W7, use the easy transfer software built into Vista or W7.

Comment: Thank you. I am actually on a computer running Vista and want to upgrade it to 7, but I want to be able to move everything I have to 7.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it restores the entire image.

**But** you have tons of options when upgrading from Vista to 7.

Mainly, you can just install 7 over Vista (it says "In Place Upgrade" in the Windows 7 Installer) and it'll keep all your settings and programs anyway.

Or use [Windows Easy Transfer](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/windows-easy-transfer.aspx) if you really want/need to wipe the drive before installing.

Comment: +1 for in-place upgrade. It can take several hours, but it is the cleanest method.